# Adding an opacity slider to an Openlayers map

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

It is straightforward to add an opacity slider for a raster layer using this line of code:

```
layer.setOpacity(this.value) to lyr_MyMapImage.setOpacity(this.value)
```

But this is untidy as the slider is located above the map.

How can I insert a slider (horizontal or vertical) onto the map to control the opacity of the layer so that it looks similar to the other map controls? Is there a plugin?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my jsfiddle I position the slider inside a proper openlayers custom control:

```
const sliderita = document.createElement('div');
sliderita.className = 'ol-control ol-unselectable slider';
sliderita.innerHTML = '<div id="sliderOSM"> <div id="custom-handle" class="ui-slider-handle"></div></div>';
map.addControl(new ol.control.Control({element: sliderita}));
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5w6sahx4/5/

Answer (score 2):

you can use jQuery slider. Example below:

```
$("#sliderLayer").slider({
    min: 0,
    max: 100,
    value: 100,
    slide: function(event, e) {
        lyr_MyMapImage.setOpacity(e.value / 100);
    },
    disabled: true
});
```

Also, here is jsFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/Svinjica/L7edtgx3/19/

Hope it helps:)

Comment: Thanks. Technically that works but I want to get the slider up onto the map. Maybe it needs some CSS?? Any ideas how to do that?

Comment: @Packwood Yes, it needs some css. I can update jsfiddle as well. Meanwhile if answer is fix to your solution you should accept it :)

Comment: @Packwood Added slider onto map. You can play as well. Possibilities are endless :)

Comment: @Svinjica I am trying to put the slider into a proper ol custom control, but struggle to do so, any hints there?

Comment: Just answered myself in my own answer